# Is there a widget which can show the current branch of a git directory in windows explorer?

Tags: git, widget, git-branch, windows-explorer

I'd like to have the information of the current branch of a git directory displayed in the windows explorer window.

That to avoid having to open a GitBash and do a `git status` or avoid checking another window (such as GitHub Desktop) to get the name of the current branch I'm on.

Also, I don't want to have to perform a right-click too.

Is there a widget or an add-on that can do this ?

I'm on windows 7.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can create a script that prints a 'status' in a txt file

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a tool for that purpose for Windows and macOS.

In case you're still interested: [RepoZ on GitHub](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ)

[image]

Comment: Would be really nice if Windows Explorer could have columns in the overview based on git information.

Comment: That's true. However I don't see a possibility to do so because these values are not static like EXIF data for example. They might get changed at any time while the Windows Explorer is open. RepoZ invalidates the form title immediately but it seems not to be a good idea to me to update the file attributes of each file and folder shown in each Windows Explorer UI.